# Openoffice/Libreoffice rounds values when saving a csv file

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I use a program to generate csv files. I use Libreoffice to check that what I think I'm doing and what I'm actually doing matches. But saving the csv file in office happens "as shown", which means it actually changes the values on me, so the result doesn't match after all.

So I have a value 1.756, it displays as 1.76 due to formatting, and then gets saved as 1.76 without warning. It's the same issue as exporting to csv, but there you can untick the "Save cell content as shown" option. I have not found a similar option for saving.

Is there a way to prevent office from secretly changing my data into garbage?

Comment: Are we talking about LibreOffice Calc? Post some test data generated by your "program". Finally, if you're only using LibreOffice to check your results, the obvious answer is NOT to save it.

Comment: Yes, it's LibreOffice Calc. I'm not sure there is a point to posting my data, since that's not the problem. It happens even if you have a csv file with just 1.0001 and nothing else. Open in calc, save, and it's just 1 now.
Not saving is what I've been doing right now, but that's not very satisfying, since autosave happens (and I don't want to switch that off), and in some instances it's useful to be able to edit things myself. I would like to be able to save.

Comment: I can only suggest that you dig around in your settings/defaults, as I have no such problem. Saving 1.0001 to a csv and retrieving it, results in a cell containing 1.0001. As does creating a csv file with a text editor and then loading it with calc.

Comment: Thank you, that's already rather helpful. I'd checked the settings before, but it seems I must have overlooked something.